# Feature request: book tag

Tags: feature-request

Much answers here come from text books and other publications. I think it's a good idea to add the possibility to add (just like tagging works) books to an answer. A lot of people can use these suggestions to read more about the topic/question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you mean a system to easily add citations to answers?

Comment: @SamuelRussell Yes, citations or books. It should work just like the tag system. Somebody adds a book, with a short summary of the book, people can add a book tag to page and cite the references.

Comment: Exactly brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not happening.  Unlike the tag taxonomy that's relatively limited, the number of books is unlimited and the number of books with reuse value across the stackexchange format is also unlimited.

Traditional citations, in the text of answers, is sufficient.